# Ubuntu Mate compatibility

Tags: pi-3b+, ubuntu

A Raspberry Pi3 B+ was outfitted with: [ubuntu-mate-18.04.2-beta1-desktop-armhf+raspi-ext4.img](https://ubuntu-mate.org/raspberry-pi/) which indicates that the B+ is the recommended hardware.   That being said, at bootup, the rainbow screen (indicating an incompatible OS) is briefly  observed (~8 seconds):

[image]

then displays an error message:

```
[2.568964] Error: Driver 'sdhost-bcm2835' is already registered, aborting...
```

proceeds to the mate desktop

- What must be done to prevent the rainbow screen + error message?
- If the OS was truly incompatible, should I expect that nothing should work?

Comment: the rainbow screen is a GPU test that appears at every boot ... how long is it staying visible?

Comment: @jsotola  Approximately 8 seconds.  I added an observed error message to the OP

Comment: This is beta software! You could try asking on https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/ubuntu-mate-18-04-2-is-coming-to-the-raspberry-pi-2-and-3/19037/12 This DOES NOT use the standard Pi kernel/firmware.